# Linux: Why do the values in smaps increase continuously?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management

I sum up the values of mappings' of the current proceess. Repeated this over a period of time. Saved the result in a file and then I plotted it. What I find a little bit odd is, that the values for the different fields of smaps seems to be increasing more or less linearly. Also I allocated some memory using the new command in c++. I freed the memory, but no recognizable difference. I was accepting some up and down movement in the plot of the fields. Unfortunately, there were not any up and down movement.

Is this behaviour normal or did I perhaps do something wrong? But I am pretty sure, that my parser works, because I checked it with pmap. My parser and pmap return for the same process the same result.

Comment: It takes effort to get memory from the OS.  Instead of returning it and asking for it again, the process simply keeps it around.  With fragmentation, it is only possible to return it sometimes anyhow.  To look for leaks, use utilities that look for leaks, not smap.

Comment: But my aim is to calculate USS and PSS. So I think smap is for those two values the right source. Do you agree?
But what to do about the fact, that it just increases?

Answer (score 0):

Allocating memory from OS is pretty expensive therefore large blocks of heap are allocated at a time. `new` tries to find empty place on the pre-allocated heap and only when there is none, it allocates another block from the OS. Deallocating from this pre-allocated heap is also done with large blocks only. (You can check [manual page “mallopt”](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mallopt) on how to tune the behavior using environment. Note that all allocations need to be done in pages, each usually 4 KiB large.)

This goes for small memory allocations. Large allocations (by default, 128 KiB or more, again tuneable with mallopt) are done with anonymous `mmap` and are deallocated when freed.

Comment: Ok, I see. This means the virtual address space of process just keeps growing? So, it gives memory back, when the process is done? But, it must be somehow possible to calculate the memory usage of a single process. For instance, this would mean that the memory usage column in htop of a running process must keep growing. But it actuallty does not. Could you give me some hints in regarding of calculating the memory usage of a single process. The values I am interested in are USS and PSS. The reason why I use smaps for it is, that you can get these two values from smaps.

Comment: @tumbler As I have written in my post, deallocations are done when there is a large block of unused memory inside the process. Regarding memory usage, it depends on which one you mean. The process has all the allocated memory reserved for itself, no other process can use it so that't how much memory it uses from the system. That's what you see in USS. But it does not mean single `new` or `delete` changes that because internally, the process has some memory preallocated but not used at the moment. You cannot see that from system-level statistics but `mallinfo` inside the process can tell you.

Comment: Does smaps give information about the real memory or the virtual memory? With memory usage I mean how much memory is consumed by a single process. I would like to reflect the real memory consumption. This means if memory gets deallocated it should be considered. My program is supposted to ask every certain ms and update the usage. Just like htop or something similar. Also e.g. smem is a script that uses smaps and some other proc file. I would like to do something similar.

Comment: I read that rss and vss are not very useful telling about the memory usage of a single process, but I read that uss and pss are more promising.

Comment: smaps give information about virtual (system) memory. This is the same information htop uses. But the virtual memory allocation does not change with every `new` or `delete`.

Comment: Put new to the side. Just forget it. How could I calculate the memory usage of a single process, but reflecting the real behaviour? Because right now it just keeps growing, which is not very helpful. So, how could I approch it?

Comment: You said at the beginning of the comments section "Regarding memory usage, it depends on which one you mean". What did you mean by "...depends on which one you mean"?

Comment: Is the continuous growing of the running process problematic? I compared my results with the one of smem  and it seems, that they are more les equal. So values of the running process keeps growing in smem, too. So my results should be fine. What do you think?

Comment: @tumbler It depends if you want the amount of memory that the process has allocated from the system or the amount of memory that data structures inside the process are using. If your process continuously grows, it may be leaking memory but you can't check that with smem, you need to take a look inside the process with valgrind or similar tool.

Comment: So how would approach these two? ("...the amount of memory that the process has allocated from the system or the amount of memory that data structures inside the process are using")